# Cannot install, php_dir for channel "pecl.php.net" is not writeable by the current user

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, php-extension

Could you please help me in solving below issue?

**Cannot install, php_dir for channel "pecl.php.net" is not writeable by the current user**

I want to install mongodb extension for php

```
macOS Calelina
Version 10.15.3

gajanan@MyMac / % csrutil status
System Integrity Protection status: disabled.
```

I have logged in as administrator

```
gajanan@MyMac / % php -v

PHP 7.3.11 (cli) (built: Dec 13 2019 19:21:21) ( NTS )

Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group

Zend Engine v3.3.11, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies


gajanan@MyMac / % pecl version

PEAR Version: 1.10.10

PHP Version: 7.3.11

Zend Engine Version: 3.3.11

Running on: Darwin MyMac.local 19.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 19.3.0: Thu Jan 9 20:58:23 PST 2020; root:xnu-6153.81.5~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64


gajanan@MyMac / % sudo pecl install mongodb

WARNING: channel "pecl.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "pecl channel-update pecl.php.net" to update

Cannot install, php_dir for channel "pecl.php.net" is not writeable by the current user


gajanan@MyMac / % sudo pecl channel-update pecl.php.net

Updating channel "pecl.php.net"

Registry directory is not writeable by the current user
```

Thanks

Comment: did you solve this issue?

Comment: I had to change the path to my local directory to solve this issue:

Here is an example of checking the configuration
`pecl config-show`

Here is an example of setting variable path:
`pecl config-set php_dir </usr/local/path>`

Comment: Thank you. but it didn't help me :/

Answer (score 2):

I had to change the path to my local directory to solve this issue.
Here is an example of checking the configuration

```
pecl config-show
```

Here is an example of setting the variable path:

```
pecl config-set php_dir </usr/local/path>
```